# Passing MySQL data through an ajax form via javascript/PHP with specialchars

Tags: php, ajax, htmlspecialchars

I've recently thrown together a basic PHP webpage that lists information pulled from an MySQL table and displays it in various sorts. I'm wanting to allow the user to add a new item to the table, edit an item in the list and delete an item in the list without refreshing the page (Ajax).

*This currently goes;*

To add/edit an article you click on a link which prompts the popover ajax form, and fills it's contents (if editing) by performing the function setEdit(comment) as below;

```
   <a class="popup-button" title="<?php echo $row['comment']; ?>" onclick="setEdit('<?php if($row['comment']){ echo $row['comment']; } else { echo "Enter comment here..."; } ?>');"><?php echo $row['listitem']; ?></a>
```

The setEdit() comment is as follows;

```
function setEdit(editcomment)
{
      if(editcomment){ document.getElementById('help-us-comment').value=editcomment; }
}
```

Which is then, after submitting the ajax form, handled by the following php code;

```
 if(isset($_POST['comment_text']))
    $comment=$_POST['comment_text'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table SET
    comment='$comment'";
```

**Problem:** I'm having constant issues trying to get the database contents through 1, 2, 3 without falling over at a new line, single or double quote. I've tried endless combinations of replacing tags, htmlspecialchars and nl2br with no half successes - where it's got to the point that it's so convoluted and encoded/decoded now that I'm assuming that there is a far simpler and obvious way that I'm missing.

The main problem happens when trying to load the data into the form, typically having either the form fall over and refuse to populate at all (typically by the a link becoming broken by the data extracted i.e. single quote or new line) or the form being populated with special characters instead of plain text to edit.

I've tried to go into as much detail as possible, but if any more is needed I'm happy to provide. Also apologies if this is an obvious fix/mistake, and I'm being an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here: storing and displaying.

To display you should look in to `htmlentities` that [makes it safe HTML](http://de.php.net/htmlentities) (it does all the quotes replacing, html encoding, etc. for you) so that your string to be safe to be displayed as plain text, or as inputs' values.

To store the data, you should sanitize your queries. You could use `mysqli` and [bind parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your input manually.

Otherwise, [say hi to Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) ;)

Comment: I've done as you've instructed throughout and have spent a few hours wrestling with methods of using htmlentities and similar to make the HTML encoding safe.

It works for the links title (title="echo htmlentites(<data>)". It works for the database that will now happily store any character. It however still refuses to accept the string in the form (which ruins editing).

I am expecting the problem stems from me echoing the encoded string into a javascript function call, that then decodes the string making it unsafe again when it gets to assigning the string to an input field value.

Comment: E.g. 1. $cleancomment = htmlentities($row['comment'], ENT_QUOTES); ... 
2. onclick='setEdit(echo $cleancomment)' ... 
3. document.getElementById('field-comment').value=cleancomment; 
4. View in ajax form that loads, nothing return (broken) ... 

with my anticipation the break happening by the stage 2->3 making the string unsafe. How to get around this?

Comment: What is the element with id='help-us-comment'? Is it a textarea or an input with type "text"? WHatever there is in `$cleancomment`, this should do it: `onclick='setEdit("<?php echo $cleancomment; ?>");'`. (this should work if it's an input, if it's a textarea, it's different...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I made some quick tests, and it looks like it should work like this for textareas too. (in jQuery it's different, that's why I thought it was here too).